# Templated Singly-Linked List

Tags: c++, beginner, linked-list, template-meta-programming

I'm really new to C++ (very surprised at the leap from Python and others to C++!). The code compiles and works well. This took *all day* to get to work, and I've the tendency to move on after I get [what I see as] basic functionality. I'd really like to become a *good* programmer, though.

I assume there are a ton of things I'm doing wrong, but I don't know what they are.

Although I've read a lot about them, I still don't fully understand when I should use a pointer. I know what they are, and what its difference is with a reference—but I haven't grokked *why* I should use one over the other.

Also, everything I've read about implementing the STL iterator (and I've read quite a bit on that) confuses the hell out of me, so I wrote a pretty basic one instead.

```
//====================
// Include Guard
#ifndef __LINKEDLIST_HPP_INCLUDED__
#define __LINKEDLIST_HPP_INCLUDED__

//===================
// Included Dependencies
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

//====================
// Forwarded Dependencies

//====================
// Classes (Header)

template<class T> class Node {
    public:
        Node();
        Node(T object);
        T getObject();
        Node* next_;

    private:
        T object_;
};

template<class T> class ListIterator {
    public:
        ListIterator(Node<T>* head_node);
        T next();

    private:
        Node<T>* current_node;
};

template<class T> struct LinkedList {
    public:
        LinkedList (T initialObject);
        ~LinkedList();
        void addObject (T addedObject);
        void removeObject (int position); 
        int getSize();
        ListIterator<T> getIterator();

    private:
        Node<T>* head_;
        Node<T>* current_;
        int size_;
};

//====================
// Class (Instantiation)

template<class T> Node<T>::Node() {};
template<class T> Node<T>::Node(T object) { object_ = object; };
template<class T> T Node<T>::getObject() { return object_; };

template<class T> ListIterator<T>::ListIterator(Node<T>* head_node) {
    current_node = head_node;
};
template<class T> T ListIterator<T>::next() {
    Node<T>* tmp_node = current_node;
    current_node = current_node->next_;
    return current_node->getObject();
};

template<class T> LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(T initialObject) {
    head_ = new Node<T>;
    current_ = new Node<T>(initialObject);
    head_->next_ = current_;
    current_->next_ = head_;
    size_ = 1;
};

// Destructor
template<class T> LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
    for (int ii = 0; ii <= size_-1; ii++) {
        Node<T>* tmpNode = head_->next_;
        head_->next_ = head_->next_->next_;
        delete tmpNode;
    };
    delete head_;
};

// Add object. Link it to head to make this circular
template<class T> void LinkedList<T>::addObject(T addedObject) {
    Node<T>* tmpNode_ = current_;
    current_->next_ = new Node<T>(addedObject);
    current_ = current_->next_;
    current_->next_ = head_;
    size_ += 1;
};

// Remove the node in the spot specified by 'position'
template<class T> void LinkedList<T>::removeObject(int position) {
    if (position <= 0) { std::cout << "ERROR: Invalid position."; }
    else if (size_ > 0 && position <= size_) {
        Node<T>* tmpNode_ = head_;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < position-1; ii++) {
            tmpNode_ = tmpNode_->next_;
        };
        delete tmpNode_->next_;
        tmpNode_->next_ = tmpNode_->next_->next_;
        size_ -= 1;
    }
    else if (size_ > 0 && position > size_) { 
        std::cout << "ERROR: LinkedList contains less than " << position 
            << " elements\n"; 
    }
    else if (size_ == 0) { std::cout << "ERROR: LinkedList is empty\n"; }
};

// Return size of Linked List
template<class T> int LinkedList<T>::getSize() { return size_; };

// Return iterator
template<class T> ListIterator<T> LinkedList<T>::getIterator() {
    return ListIterator<T>(head_);
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **`Node`**

   1. There is no need to make `Node` public. `LinkedList` and `ListIterator` need it but client of your library doesn't. So consider hiding it from him. For example by defining `Node` within the `LinkedList` class.
   2. `Node()`

      1. It would be cleaner if `next_` would be set to [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) (if in C++11 or above) or [`NULL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL)/`0` (otherwise).
      2. There should be no use for default constructor anyway. (See below notes on `LinkedList<T>::head_`.) In fact use of this constructor requires type `T` to be [DefaultConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible) while there is no need to require that.
   3. `Node(T object)`

      1. Use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) instead of assigning to members in constructor's body.
      2. It would be cleaner if `next_` would be set to [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) (if in C++11 or above) or [`NULL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL)/`0` (otherwise).
      3. Change argument to `const T&` if you are pre-C++11.
      4. Otherwise use [move semantics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) when constructing `object_` from `object`. And also possibly add `const T&` overload anyway.
   4. `getObject()`

      1. Return `T&` instead of `T` as it would not require copying of the object.
      2. And add `const` overload which returns `const T&`.
   5. `next_`

      1. Should not be a `public` member! Make it private and grant to `LinkedList` and `ListIterator` access to for example using `friend`.
   6. It could be useful to forbid copying of `Node` objects as it seems there is no use in that. To do that use [`boost::noncopyable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/noncopyable.html) if you have [Boost](http://www.boost.org/). If you don't then either explicitly "delete" copy constructor and assignment operator (if in C++11 or above) or make them `private` without defining them.
2. **`ListIterator`**

   1. As you noted yourself your iterator differs significantly from what C++ considers and iterator. This means in particular that it will not be usable with any STL function. Or other libraries that use "normal iterators".
   2. As a side note I will mention that [`boost::iterator_facade`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) makes it much easier to write proper iterator. But it requires use of [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).
   3. With your current design as it is how will you know that the iteration ended? There is no method in `ListIterator` that says that. With your current implementation (of cyclic list - see comments in `LinkedList`) any iteration would be infinite unless you would count elements yourself during iteration and stop at `getSize`.
   4. `ListIterator(Node<T>* head_node)`

      1. Use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) instead of assigning to members in constructor's body.
   5. `next()`

      1. Implementation incorrectly returns value from `current_node`. It seems that instead it should return value from `tmp_node`.
      2. Return `T&` instead of `T` as it would not require copying of the object. (But to do that you have to do the same for `Node<T>::getObject()` as commented above.)
   6. Consider having also a `ConstListIterator` which uses `const Node<T>*` and returns `const T&` from `next()`. This would allow to iterate over `const LinkedList` object. With some template magic this could be done with single implementation.
3. **`LinkedList`**

   1. From implementation it seems to be a cyclic list. Was this intended?
   2. I don't follow the idea behind `head_` node. I think that it is not needed. Not to mention that it's value could be undefined while it will show up during iteration.
   3. The class would be a bit more usable if you could add element at arbitrary position. Given by integer (to make your design consistent) or iterator (to be consistent with previous comment).
   4. The class would be a bit more usable if you could remove element based on iterator. Or else allow the iterator to return it's position as integer. But remove by iterator is more in line with C++ (STL) style.
   5. The class would be a bit more usable if it allowed also `const` iteration. So `getIterator()` should have a `const` overload returning `const` iterator (as commneted above).
   6. Size in C++ is usually expressed using [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) type. So should be also positions in your case.
   7. There should be a default constructor making an empty list.
   8. `LinkedList(T initialObject)`

      1. Consider making it `explicit` so that it cannot be used for conversion.
      2. Add also second argument being count of initial elements. And default it to `1`. It would make the constructor a bit more flexible and little cost. (And also it will match typical STL container constructors.)
      3. Change argument to `const T&` if you are pre-C++11.
      4. Otherwise use [move semantics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) when constructing `object_` from `object`. And also possibly add `const T&` overload anyway.
      5. Use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) instead of assigning to members in constructor's body.
   9. You should properly define copy constructor and assignment operator. Or at least forbid them (as already mentioned for `Node`).
   10. Consider adding other constructors. For example from a range of elements of other list (by positions or by iterators).
   11. `~LinkedList()`

       1. `<= size_-1` in loop condition is risky. Once you change to (`unsigned`) `std::size_t` (as commented above) `size_-1` for `size_ == 0` would wrap around `0` and result in maximal positive value. The loop would be infinite. On the other hand note that alternative `< size_` results in infinite loop for `size_` being already maximal positive value. (Which however seems less likely than being `0`.)
       2. In loop use `++ii` rather than `ii++`. On modern compilers with integers it doesn't matter really. But it is cleaner to write so. And could make a difference if `ii` would be an iterator rather than integer. So it is better to have good habits.
   12. `addObject(T addedObject)`

       1. Unused `tmpNode_` local variable.
       2. I would write `++size_` instead of `size_ += 1`. Feels more natural. But in the end there should be no difference.
       3. You are making no check against exceeding maximal positive value for `size_`.
       4. Change argument to `const T&` if you are pre-C++11.
       5. Otherwise use [move semantics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) when constructing `Node<T>` from `addedObject`. And also possibly add `const T&` overload anyway.
   13. `removeObject(int position)`

       1. Instead of writing to `cout` use exceptions. There are also other means (like returning error code). But outputting to `cout` is of no use. (And `cerr` seems more adequate anyway...)
       2. `< position-1` in loop condition is risky. Once you change to (`unsigned`) `std::size_t` (as commented above) `position-1` for `position == 0` would wrap around `0` and result in maximal positive value. The loop would be go crazy (although it would not be infinite). Instead of that you could start with `ii = 1`.
       3. In loop use `++ii` rather than `ii++`. On modern compilers with integers it doesn't matter really. But it is cleaner to write so. And could make a difference if `ii` would be an iterator rather than integer. So it is better to have good habits.
       4. You could extract the loop fragment to separate (`private`) method which returns `Node<T>*` of given position. It would make code somewhat cleaner. And also you could reuse the method in other functions that I recommended to add (in comments above).
       5. You should first store `tmpNode_->next_` in a local variable. Then set `tmpNode_->next_` to `tmpNode_->next_->next_`. And only then `delete` the local variable. Current code uses `next_` of already deleted object and sooner or later will crash on that.
       6. I would write `--size_` instead of `size_ -= 1`. Feels more natural. But in the end there should be no difference.
       7. This method is badly implemented anyway. For example on a list constructed with the single element constructor calling `removeObject(1)` will actually `delete` the node from `head_` but will never update `head_` member. Maybe changing the condition to `position < size_` (and next to `position >= size_`) would correct it. But since the idea of `head_` is likely wrong this method would change anyway.
   14. `getSize()`

       1. Should be a `const` method as it doesn't change the object.

There are also other possible extensions. For example you could add allocator support. Or allow in-place construction of elements. But those are more advanced topics. Maybe save them for later.

Comment: I thought this was going to go unnoticed! The cyclic iterator was purposeful; the objects I'm going to use this for will all have unique ID numbers, so the iterator will end when the ID of one of the objects repeats. Thanks so much for your corrections—I'll start working on them immediately.

Comment: One more question: If I define Node within Linked List—then I'd have to define the iterator within Linked List too, right? (If I did that, wouldn't Node and the iterator have to be public anyway?)

Comment: @AmagicalFishy If `Node` is made `private` within `LinkedList` then either `ListIterator` must be defined within `LinkedList` or must be a `friend` of it.